# Microsoft Azure: obtaining public IP on Linux with azure API for Python

Tags: python, linux, azure, networking

Could someone advice me or show me example of how to obtain public IP through Azure API on linux? I know that I can obtain public IP through *wget*, *curl* etc. but those use external domain and I would like to avoid it.
There is some SDK for Python but I couldn't run any function.

I think maybe one of these my return what I need:
[NetworkInterfaceIPConfigurationsOperations class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_02_01.operations.networkinterfaceipconfigurationsoperations?view=azure-python)
[NetworkInterfacesOperations class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_02_01.operations.networkinterfacesoperations?view=azure-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the Python tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-get-started?view=azure-python

And then some network example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/network?view=azure-python

Once you're confortable with the NetworkManagementClient client, you can do:

```
    result_get = network_client.public_ip_addresses.get(
        resource_group_name,
        public_ip_name,
    )
```

network_client.public_ip_addresses being an instance of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2018_02_01.operations.publicipaddressesoperations?view=azure-python