# Azure Python API to check if a VM has public IP

Tags: python, azure, azure-vm, azure-rest-api

My use-case is:

1. Identify if a VM has public IP(T/F).
2. (Optional) Print the Public IP.

I have been trying out a lot of combinations mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719739/microsoft-azure-obtaining-public-ip-on-linux-with-azure-api-for-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728871/get-ip-from-vm-object-using-azure-sdk-in-python). My primary goal is to identify if a VM has public IP associated or not. Seems like the azure python sdk has changed over time and some of the old solutions are not working.

I found a simple azure cli command which does the job but I am not able to find the corresponding api for it.

`az vm list-ip-addresses --name testVM`

Is there an API call that can give the same information. If not, whats the best way to identify if an azure VM has public IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Azure VM named **`srivm`** with **Public IP** as below:

[image]

To fetch this via Python API, I created one ***service principal*** with ***client secret*** as below:

[image]

I tried using below code to get **Public IP** address of virtual machine and got it successfully:

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=<tenantID>,  #Your TenantID
    client_id=<appID>,     #Your AppID
    client_secret=<secret>    #Your Client Secret Value
)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id=<subscriptionID> #Your SubscriptionID
)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id=<subscriptionID> #Your SubscriptionID
    )

rg = 'sri'     #Resource group name
publicip = 'xxxxxxxxx'   #Subnet name
result_get = network_client.public_ip_addresses.get(
       rg, publicip
    )
print(result_get.ip_address)
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can try using the same code in your environment in order to fetch the **Public IP** of virtual machine.

Make sure to install required **modules** and assign required **role** to the service principal before running the code.